# Excel VBA converting fracture binary into decimal problem

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngLjL.png)I want to calculate first the left part of the "." with bin2dec. but i have problems with the right side. It always says 0. my expectation is to sum the two sides so i get a 15.something number

```
Sub Konvertálás_Kattintás()
Dim szamok As String
Dim hossz As Long
Dim karakterek As Variant
Dim sum As Integer
Dim ss As Integer
Dim hatvany As Integer
szamok = Range("F2").Value
ReDim karakterek(1 To Len(szamok))

For i = 1 To Len(szamok)
karakterek(i) = Mid(szamok, i, 1)
Next i

For j = 1 To Len(karakter)
If (karakter(i) = "1") Then
hatvany = hatvany * 2
sum = 2 ^ (-hatvany)
End If
Next j

MsgBox (WorksheetFunction.Bin2Dec(Range("E2") + sum))

End Sub
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include sample data and the results you are expecting.

Comment: `For j = 1 To Len(karakter)` should be `For j = lbound(karakter) To ubound(karakter)`

Comment: Is the array called `karakterek` or `karakter`? There seems to be some confusion in that area.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cohs0wE

Comment: i did what you suggested still 15

Comment: You declare `hatvany` as an integer which instantiates it with an initial value of zero. Then you use it without modification and try to double it. Zero × 2 is still zero no matter how many times you do it in a loop. Then you try to use it as a negative exponent. 2 to the power of zero is 1. So your result should be 15+1 or 16, not 15.